# What does `came off the back` mean?

Tags: grammar, articles

Here's the full statement:

> Keyless SSL was interesting and if I recall correctly it came off the
>   back of financial institutions not being able to disclose their keys.

Is it okay to use `came from` instead?

Answer (score 1):

This saying means "following, as a result of;" the phrase doesn't work as "came from the back"

Comment: I was thinking of replacing `came off the back of financial institutions` with `came from financial institutions`. Not `came from the back of`

Comment: Yes, your replacement is correct. However, consider "originated from" as this makes the meaning more explicit.